# Inheritance (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose there's an instance of a derived class in main. When you call a member function, is the version of the function in the base class called, or just the overloaded version in the derived class? Additionally, if you have a pointer of the base class that is initialized to point to an instance of the derived class which constructors run, if any?

Comment: is the member function `virtual`?

Comment: Also I'm having trouble understanding the second sentence.  Assigning an address to a pointer doesn't call _any_ constructors.  Creating an instance calls a destructor, but that's unrelated to pointer types.

Comment: For the first questions sake lets say its virtual. for the second question, i guess more simply put, does calling pointers run constructors or destructors?

Comment: No, pretty much nothing to do with pointer variables is related to constructors or destructors.  If I make a nametag, that doesn't make a new human being.

Comment: And if I change the name on a nametag, that doesn't kill anyone.

Comment: Rather than try to describe the code you are wondering about, it is much easier to write the code you are wondering about.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    void nonvirtual() {std::cout << "Base::nonvirtual()\n";}
    virtual void isvirtual() {std::cout << "Base::isvirtual()\n";}
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    void nonvirtual() {std::cout << "Derived::nonvirtual()\n";}
    virtual void isvirtual() {std::cout << "Derived::isvirtual()\n";}
};
```

What's invisible here, is that because the existence of `virtual` members, The compiler creates a function table for the class `Base` with two pointers (one for each virtual function), and each pointer points at one of the virtual functions.  The compiler creates a *nearly identical* table for derived, with it's two pointers pointing at the `Derived` versions of those functions.  This magic also adds a "virtual function pointer" to each class instance, which points at one of these tables.

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.nonvirtual(); //this prints Derived::nonvirtual()
    d.isvirtual(); //this prints Derived::isvirtual()

    Base b;
    b.nonvirtual(); //this prints Base::nonvirtual()
    b.isvirtual(); //this prints Base::isvirtual()
}
```

This creates space for a each variable in main, and calls the default constructor for each of them.  The constructor invisibly sets the invisible virtual function pointer as pointing to the table that points to the correct functions.  All the functions to the obvious things.

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    Derived* dptr = &d;
    dptr->nonvirtual(); //this prints Derived::nonvirtual()
    dptr->isvirtual(); //this prints Derived::isvirtual()

    Base* bptr = &d;
    bptr->nonvirtual(); //this prints Base::nonvirtual()
    bptr->isvirtual(); //this prints Derived::isvirtual() !!!!!!!
}
```

Pointers and references are where it gets tricky.  If we create a `Derived*` and point it at a `Derived` instance, it continues to behave as obvious.  What's *not* immediately obvious is what happens when a `Base*` points at a `Derived` instance.  If you call a non-virtual member function, the compiler sees that you're using a `Base` pointer, and uses the `Base` version of that function.  Relatively straightforward.  If the member function in `Base` is `virtual`, then the compiler magic kicks in.  It checks the invisible virtual pointer member, and checks the table it points at.  In this case, it points at the table with the `Derived` member functions.  The compiler knows that `isvirtual` is the second virtual member, so it calls the second function in that table, which is the `Derived::isvirtual` function.

For related reasons, if a class can be used as a base class, you should *almost always* give it a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That's exactly why I included `virtual_no` from the first draft.  However, given your misunderstanding, I'll rename these.

Comment: Oh, hah, I completely misread it when skimming through the code. My bad. :(